# How to enable TWBT for Spacefox graphic set in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

After using [Spacefox Graphic Set](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=129219.0) in Dwarf Fortress, text is displayed as graphic tiles(for example, `idlers: 8` is shown as `idlers<rocks> 8`), but I want text to be text.

[image]

There seems to be a dfhack plugin called [TWBT](https://github.com/mifki/df-twbt), which is designed to resolve this problem. I've already installed dfhack, but due to the lack of documentation, I don't know how to install TWBT and get everything work.

I'm playing vanilla Dwarf Fortress v43.03 under macOS. It seems that with a Lazy Newb Pack, even a newbie can fix this issue easily, but unfortunately the latest version of LNP hasn't supported save files from v43.03 yet :(